# Move tokens from multiple HD addresses

Tags: solidity, hd-wallets

I am trying to find information regarding how to move funds (USDT for example) from multiple HD wallets in a single transaction to pay only once and not have to pay for each one separately. From what I understand, the exchanges do it through smart contracts to move funds from millions of hot wallets.
Does anyone have any ideas? I can't find any information about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it is hardware wallet that you own, then you must make one tx per wallet since you can only make a transaction from one source account. If it is "virtual" hardware wallet, like some wallet an exchange made for you and said it is a "hardware wallet" then they can do anything with your funds, including the loss of them. But that's not a true hardware wallet. With hardware wallet you have full control over it and nobody else, and there can be only 1 tx per account

Comment: the exchanges have single wallet where they concentrate all the funds and these funds accumulate the amount of assets for all the users of the exchange. It may also be a contract. Nobody is really sharing this info as it would be a hackers paradise.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a reference here for `multicall`

https://solidity-by-example.org/app/multi-call/

Then you can send with one transaction and calling multiple times.